# changing the port 80 if it was busy

Tags: python, localhost

i have an assignment to make a web server on the TCP by using LAN , the project is to make a request to localhost on port 80 and present "hi" in a browser and to present "404 not found" if the request is wrong, i have a problem with being port 80 is busy, it stop working when using any port but 80, the hint from the assignment is "If you run your server on a host that already has a Web server running on it, then you should use a different port than port 80 for your Web server." and my code is :

```py
from socket import *

import os


def test():
    serverPort = 80
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1)

    print("web server on port", serverPort)

    while True:
        print("ready to serve")
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        try:
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            print(message)
            filename = message.split()[1]
            print(filename[1:])
            print(filename, '||', filename[1])
            f = open(filename[1:])
            outputdata = f.read()
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata.encode())
            connectionSocket.close()
        except Exception:
            print("404 Not Found")
            connectionSocket.send("""404 Not Found\r\n""".encode())
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you need to check if port already in use or not

```
def check(port):
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    return s.connect_ex(('localhost', serverPort)) == 0
```